# Import Android project from command line

Tags: android, android-studio, command-line

I have a Android project **without .iml** project file. In Android Studio i can *File -> New -> Import Project*, choose my project folder and .iml file will be created. **How can i do the same from command line in Windows?** I have a big project, so i need recursive choise files from folders.

Comment: Do you want to create the iml file? If so, why? All required information for project setup is in the gradle file

Comment: By the way, if the gradle files are present, you don't need to use "Import Project". Just use open project and select the project folder

Comment: I want to build apk (use 'gradlew assembleDebug'), its doesnt work without .iml file. If i create .iml file from Android Studio (File -> New -> Import Project) 'gradlew assembleDebug' will work

Comment: `gradlew assembleDebug` should work without the `.iml` file. Something else is missing then. Is the  `gradlew` or `gradlew.bat` file missing?

Comment: Or to clarify, what exactly isn't working when executing `gradlew assembleDebug` ?

Comment: @JensV gradlew.bat not missing. I build it now, problem was in my VPN (gradle not synchronize). Thanks! :)